# Cmake Visual Studio 2013 error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cmake, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to run a simple program through cmake gui and I receive the following output. I am not really sure what the problem is and forgive me, because I am quite new to this.  I have also uninstalled and installed visual studio 2012 and 2013 to see if that would make a difference. I am using Visual Studio 2013 as the compiler and get the following configuration error.

My environment is :
Windows 7 enterprise 64 bit
Cmake gui 2.8.12.2 
Visual Studio 2013 Professional

```
The C compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.21005.1
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.21005.1
Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 12
Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 12 -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
  12.0/VC/bin/cl.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: C:/Users/PM&R/Desktop/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:C:\PROGRA~2\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
  cmTryCompileExec3676669247.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug
  /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0

  Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 12.0.21005.1


  [Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.18444]


  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.





  Build started 3/31/2014 2:27:43 PM.


  Project
  "C:\Users\PM&R\Desktop\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec3676669247.vcxproj"
  on node 1 (default targets).



  C:\Users\PM&R\Desktop\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec3676669247.vcxproj(60,85):
  error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded.  An error occurred
  while parsing EntityName.  Line 60, position 85.


  Done Building Project
  "C:\Users\PM&R\Desktop\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec3676669247.vcxproj"
  (default targets) -- FAILED.





  Build FAILED.






  "C:\Users\PM&R\Desktop\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec3676669247.vcxproj"
  (default target) (1) ->


    C:\Users\PM&R\Desktop\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec3676669247.vcxproj(60,85): error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 60, position 85.





      0 Warning(s)

      1 Error(s)





  Time Elapsed 00:00:00.02






  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/PM&R/Desktop/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/PM&R/Desktop/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: What target generator you using?

Comment: Do you have write permission to User "PM&R"
 personal folders? Have you removed completely cmake's cache when you have changed generator? Try to generate build system in some folder like C:/Tmp, if it is not just a write issue/illegal character on path issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to generate build system in the folder C:/Tmp to test if the problem is related to corrupted cache or path issues. To build it to the folder stated in the question:

- Check that you do have write permission in "PM&R" personal folders
- Remove cmake cache when you change the generator